# Anagram function says "ellhe" and "hello" are anagrams

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to check whether two given strings are anagrams.

```
def Anagram(Word1, Word2):
    if len(Word1.lower()) == len(Word2.lower()):
        for Char in Word1.lower():
            if Char in Word2.lower():
                return (Word2,"Is An Anagram Of", Word1)
            else:
                return (Word2, "Is Not A Anagram", Word1)
    else:
        return (Word2, "Is Not A Anagram", Word1)

print(Anagram("Hello", "ellhe"))
```

The problem is that this prints that it is an anagram when it is not.  FOr instance, it says that "ellhe" and "hello" are anagrams, but they differ by one letter ('o' vs a second 'e'). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to do more than check if the letters are the same, you also need to check that the counts are the same

Comment: you return immediately after the comparison of the first characters

Comment: Your function returns on the first Char. It doesn't check the whole string.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning after only checking one letter, but your method is flawed anyway. Implemented correctly it will return true if the words contain the same letters, but will disregard how often they occur.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things:
1) You're returning as soon as one character matches, not when the entire word matches
2) I believe you need to add some logic to handle situations where the same letter appears multiple times. Otherwise, helo and hello will show as anagrams of each other.

Answer (score 0):

This is a one-liner: sort both strings and compare the sorted lists of characters:

```
if sorted(word1.lower()) ==
   sorted(word2.lower()):
```

I trust you can do the rest of the routine, as you've already handled that logic.